# Adding error, simple questions

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Rookie Question! When I run this and I put the number of guests as 2, I should have 2 small pizzas because the number isn't bigger than 3 (to make it a medium) and when I run it it tells me 0 for all sizes. Rounding error? How do I fix this? --English please, I'm a beginner :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //promt user
    cout << "Please enter number of guests:";
    int attendees;
    cin >> attendees;

    int large_pizzas = attendees / 7 ;
    cout << "purchase " << large_pizzas << " large pizzas" << endl;

    int medium_pizzas = large_pizzas % 3 ;
    cout << "purchase " << medium_pizzas << " medium pizzas" << endl;

    int small_pizzas = medium_pizzas % 1 ;
    cout << "purchase " << small_pizzas << " small pizzas" << endl;
```

Comment: Step through it in a debugger. And think about what `% 1` means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you can tweak how you want:

```
#include <iostream>

#define LARGE_PIZZA_SHARE 7     // 7 persons can share 1 large pizza
#define MEDIUM_PIZZA_SHARE 3    // 3 persons can share 1 medium pizza
#define SMALL_PIZZA_SHARE 1     // 1 person - 1 small pizza

int main()
{
    int attendees = 0;
    cout << "Enter number of attendees: ";
    cin >> attendees;

    int largePizzaCount = 0;
    int mediumPizzaCount = 0;
    int smallPizzaCount = 0;

    if (attendees >= LARGE_PIZZA_SHARE)
    {
        largePizzaCount = attendees / LARGE_PIZZA_SHARE;
        attendees = attendees % LARGE_PIZZA_SHARE; 
    }

    if (attendees >= MEDIUM_PIZZA_SHARE)
    {
        mediumPizzaCount = attendees / MEDIUM_PIZZA_SHARE;
        attendees = attendees % MEDIUM_PIZZA_SHARE;
    }

    if (attendees >= SMALL_PIZZA_SHARE)
    {
        smallPizzaCount = attendees / SMALL_PIZZA_SHARE;
    }

    cout << "You require: " << largePizzaCount << " large pizzas, " << mediumPizzaCount << " medium pizzas, and " << smallPizzaCount << " small pizzas!" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you're awesome!